Can I Use Square D 60A Non-Fused A/C Disconnect with #14 NM Cable?
I am installing a 15A mini split, and the disconnect I'm using is a 60A non-fused Square D QO200TR. It provides no overcurrent protection and is pretty much just an on/off switch. It's protected upstream in my panel by a 15A double pole breaker. What's confusing me is that when I was looking at the torque specs, I realized they only specify #2-#8 AWG wire at 45 in/lbs for the switch. The line terminals say they are suitable for #14-4. I'm using 14 AWG, so I wanted to make sure this is okay. If so, is there any way to tell what torque I would use? It seems odd that the line terminals have a different rating than the switch, but I don't know if this is common. I had thought that maybe I could swap the switch with a 15A QO breaker (I saw some reviews that mentioned doing this), but after researching on Schneider's site, I found that these enclosures are not UL listed for a breaker.
This is the link to what I bought: https://www.supplyhouse.com/Square-D-QO200TR-AC-Disconnect-Non-Fusible-60-Amp-240-V
I appreciate any help!
This is a picture of the disconnect. The open knockout at the bottom will be covered. I'm running LFNC to the surge protector on the left.


I think the the only way to use it is to pigtail/connect #8 to the #14.  #8 is the smallest you can use on the terminals.  Or get a smaller disconnect.

Please revise your title to actually ask the question and not just state that you have one. See [ask].

What is your question? This overall device is rated for #2-#8 so anything outside of that range is off-label. That said, I've knowingly used them before with #12 and #10 and they have worked just fine.
